# Google-Chrome download rate 700KB/s but total internet speed is 350KB/s

Tags: google-chrome, download, 3g

I did a quick google search on this bug/problem but found nothing, so now I'm here hoping you guys know.

Google-Chrome version: Version 39.0.2171.95 m
3g internet recever diagnistics:
Modem name : 
    HSPA USB MODEM
Firmware version : 
    IX1B5200XX
IMEI : 
    867622002213927
IMSI : 
    222881450857240

Operator Information
PIN code status : 
    READY
Network code : 
    22288
Network selection mode : 
    auto
Network mode : 
    UTRAN
Signal strength : 
    level 4

Network Status
CS network registration : 
    registered, home PLMN
PS network registration : 
    registered, home PLMN
PS network attachment : 
    attached

I use a 3g internet recever for my internet (there is actualy no cable from the world to my house) which has a max speed of +-350KB/s, but when I download something big (500mb+) my download speed on Google-Chrome every so often tells me that my download speed is 700KB/s. I can  literly see my download speed from second to second and confirm that it is nowere close to that speed.

Why would Google-Chrome then think it is so high? Is there a way to make it stop and to see the actual download speed?

edit: also the huge download in which the problem occured finished and gave me an error:

> android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe: Unknown network error.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your units? Is the 3g receiver 350KB/s or 350Kbps? These are very different units. Are you sure Chrome is reporting 700kb/s? I believe Chrome reports in KB/s, which is a different unit entirely. Perhaps you mean 350KBps and 700KB/s? There are no units with `k` in them, and the `KB` and `Kb` units are very different and Kb/s and Kbps are different units too.

Comment: Is Chrome reporting the speed momentarily or for a long period? If it's just showing it for a few seconds, it's likely just a buffering glitch somewhere - Chrome measures "how fast the file is arriving at the destination" now "how much bandwidth do you have?" - they don't necessarily match exactly. Note also that Chrome is not an analysis tool, the speed is only there to give you an approximate idea of progress.

Comment: everything is in KB/s and the period is like 5 seconds with an update every second so it just goes to 700KB/s for 5 seconds and then just goes down to 300KB/s like it was before

Comment: @user280730 - Sounds like a glitch in Chrome.  I would report the issue to Google.

Comment: it was actualy telling me I was doing 1050KB/s just now (I wish it was true)

Answer (score 0):

Network speed is measured by amount of data divided by time. Picking the wrong time frame can give illusion of higher speed. think about packets of size 2kb coming every 2 second, obviously, your "average speed" is 1kbps however, if your measurement window is 1s, then you get 2, 0, 2, 0, ... for your speed, which once averaged, gives you 1kbps again. The reality though is more complicated since packets are not received regularly and the PHY layer may need to go back and forth if a corrupted packet is received, so there is a lot going on before you can measure your application layer data rate (e.g. download rate).

It should not have to do much with your corrupted download, that is, they might have the same root cause or not.

Comment: but would you think a downlod speed can be higher for several seconds just because packet sizes, i mean, sounds wierd considering the download speed matches up the rest of the time

Comment: On connections with a lot of delay, that happens. Actually, even with normal connections it happens. Go to your task manager-> network if you see a zig-zag pattern up and down, this is the real reason. Like I said, speed is defined when you have a continuous stream, but packets are not continues hence v=dx/dt is not as well defined.